# Keep language in link cake php

Tags: php, cakephp

Core.php

```
<?php

Configure::write('debug', 2);

Configure::write('Error', array(
    'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleError',
    'level' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED,
    'trace' => true
));

Configure::write('Exception', array(
    'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleException',
    'renderer' => 'ExceptionRenderer',
    'log' => true
));

Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');

Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php'
));

Configure::write('Security.salt', '7f19b3be4ee7a22fa2e415279337475c4c7a97e8');
Configure::write('Security.cipherSeed', '474149355628227626166274362321');

Configure::write('Acl.classname', 'DbAcl');
Configure::write('Acl.database', 'default');

$engine = 'File';

$duration = '+999 days';
if (Configure::read('debug') > 0) {
    $duration = '+10 seconds';
}
$prefix = 'myapp_';

Cache::config('_cake_core_', array(
    'engine' => $engine,
    'prefix' => $prefix . 'cake_core_',
    'path' => CACHE . 'persistent' . DS,
    'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
    'duration' => $duration
));

Cache::config('_cake_model_', array(
    'engine' => $engine,
    'prefix' => $prefix . 'cake_model_',
    'path' => CACHE . 'models' . DS,
    'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
    'duration' => $duration
));
?>
```

Bootstrap.php

```
<?php
Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File'));
CakePlugin::load('DebugKit');
Configure::write('Config.languages', array('jap', 'eng'));
Configure::write('Config.language', 'jap');

Configure::write('Dispatcher.filters', array(
    'AssetDispatcher',
    'CacheDispatcher'
));
App::uses('CakeLog', 'Log');
CakeLog::config('debug', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'types' => array('notice', 'info', 'debug'),
    'file' => 'debug',
));
CakeLog::config('error', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'types' => array('warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency'),
    'file' => 'error',
));
?>
```

routes.php

```
Router::connect('/:language/:controller/:action/*', array(), array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
Router::connect('/:language/login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'), array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
Router::connect('/:language/logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'), array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
Router::connect('/:language/dashboard', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'display'), array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));

Router::connect('/:language/:controller/*', array(), array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
Router::connect('/:language/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'), array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
```

appcontroller.php

```
<?php

App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Session',
        'Cookie',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
            'authError' => 'You must be logged in to view this page.',
            'loginError' => 'Invalid Username or Password entered, please try again.',
    ));
    public $helpers = array('Html' => array('className' => 'MyHtml'));

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('login');
        $this->_setLanguage();
    }

    private function _setLanguage() {
        if ($this->Cookie->read('language') && !$this->Session->check('Config.language')) {
            $this->Session->write('Config.language', $this->Cookie->read('language'));
        } else if (isset($this->params['language']) && ($this->params['language'] != $this->Session->read('Config.language'))) {
            $this->Session->write('Config.language', $this->params['language']);
            $this->Cookie->write('language', $this->params['language'], false, '20 days');
        }
    }

    public function redirect($url, $status = NULL, $exit = true) {
        if (!isset($url['language']) && $this->Session->check('Config.language')) {
            $url['language'] = $this->Session->read('Config.language');
        }
        parent::redirect($url, $status, $exit);
    }

}
?>
```

I wanna use multiple languages for my application . it's ok but I want when I click link

```
echo $this->Html->link("Home", array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'index'));
```

like that . The application auto add language in my link like `http://mydomain/TestInternationalChange/jap/posts/index` 
not `http://mydomain/TestInternationalChange/posts/index` 
. my apphelper.php and myhtmlhelper.php are null .

Comment: It's not a good idea to share your `Security.salt` nor your `Security.cipherSeed`

Comment: Also I don't understand very well. Do you want to have a link like `http://mydomain/TestInternationalChange/jap/posts/index` or `http://mydomain/TestInternationalChange/posts/index`?

Comment: i had a link http://mydomain/TestInternationalChange/jap/posts/ I want redirect to link http://mydomain/TestInternationalChange/jap/posts/index but when I click a link url like that http://mydomain/TestInternationalChange/posts/index

Comment: Read article: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/kicaj/2013/01/27/internationalization_with_static_and_dynamic_content_routing_and_switching

Comment: thanks but it's not work